# Google script onChange event doens't fire anymore

Tags: onchange

I have a google script in a spreadsheet based on onChange trigger.
The script worked perfectly for a couple of months and the suddenly stopped working. The script was not modified, no changes were made, it simply didn't work anymore, without any error messages.

For the purpose of this question, I deleted all script except a simple message based on the trigger:

```
function onChange()
{
   Logger.log('Working');
   Browser.msgBox('Working');
}
```

The script still doesn't work, but it is working in a different spreadsheet.
Triggers are obviously installed (since it worked before), on both spreadsheets, everything is the same (apparently), but the function doesn't fire anymore on the first spreadsheet, it fires only on the other one.

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening and how can it be fixed?
Thank you.

Comment: Is there anything in the execution transcript? You could also try function onChange(e) { logger.Log(e) }

Comment: Nope, there is nothing, it simply doesn't fire. (I've tried to log what you suggested, but it's empty).

Comment: Did you try deleting and reinstalling the trigger?

Comment: Yep, also tried that. Same result.